# Trigger animation when Command is Executed in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, relaycommand, routed-events

I have a View Model that defines a `RelayCommand` which multiple controls have as their `Command` binding. I would like to trigger an animation on all the controls that are bound to this command when it executes (or is done executing). The command can be executed by UI controls and in the View Model from a Model event.

**Just as an example** imagine I want a `Button` to flash Gold when the `MyCommand` binding is executed, be it from the button click or somewhere else. A `Hyperlink`, also bound to `MyCommand`, would end up making the button flash, although I am not looking for this specific solution (hyperlink triggers button flash directly). Here is the XAML for this example:

```
<Button Content="My Command"
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}">

    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="buttonBrush"
                         Color="DimGray" />
    </Button.Background>

    <Button.Resources>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Key="flash"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                                   KeyTime="0:0:0" />
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                                   KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="DimGray"
                                 KeyTime="0:0:0.7" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Button.Resources>

    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.Executed">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="buttonBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="goldFlash" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>

<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
        My Command...
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

I made up `RoutedEvent="Binding.Executed"` to demonstrate what I am trying to do, I understand that that event doesn't exist.

### Update

Following @BionicCode's suggestion I added `Executing` and `Executed` events to my `RelayCommand` class. In my View Model, I receive these events when the command is executed by a button in my UI.

I then added a `MyCommandExecuted` event to the View Model that gets raised when the command's `Executed` event occurs.

In my `MainWindow`, I added an event handler for the `MyCommandExecuted` event and this event is working properly.

Next I created a `RoutedEvent` in `MainWindow` (sorry, this is VB.Net), using code from [How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event):

```
' Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
' This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
Public Shared ReadOnly TapEvent As RoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, GetType(RoutedEventHandler), GetType(MainWindow))

' Provide CLR accessors for the event
Public Custom Event Tap As RoutedEventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As RoutedEventHandler)
        Me.AddHandler(TapEvent, value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As RoutedEventHandler)
        Me.RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.RaiseEvent(e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

and I raise this event in the `MyCommandExecuted` event handler:

```
' This method raises the Tap event
Private Sub RaiseTapEvent()
    Dim newEventArgs As New RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.TapEvent)
    MyBase.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs)
End Sub

' For demonstration purposes we raise the event when the MyButtonSimple is clicked
Private Sub MyCommandExecuted() Handles _myViewModel.MyCommandExecuted
    Me.RaiseTapEvent()
End Sub
```

This code gets executed so everything up to here is working. Finally, in the XAML, I created an `EventTrigger` for `local:MainWindow.Tap`:

```
<Border Width="100" Height="100" x:Name="MyBorder" Background="AliceBlue">
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MainWindow.Tap">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                  FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                  Duration="0:0:2">
                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                                               KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="DarkOrange"
                                               KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

This doesn't work... events don't "bubble down" (makes sense) but if you put the `EventTrigger` at the `Window` level like in @BionicCode's example, **it works**, so problem solved.

Comment: Do you want to start the animation precisely when the **MyCommand** is fired or just when user presses the button or hyperlink? For the second case, you can accomplish it using **EventTriggers**. For the first case, it's a little bit more complicated, and I honestly don't see why would you want such behavior.

Comment: @bus1hero the timing does not have to be precise so the second case you describe is what I am looking for. The example with a button and hyperlink is just to demonstrate a simple scenario but I am not interested in having the button listen for an event from the hyperlink or vice-versa, I would like it to be based on the command binding itself. A similar behavior would be a virtual keyboard that has commands for each key and lets you click a key button or press a physical key, both executing the same command. If you pressed the key, the key button could flash to show the key was pressed.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville There is nothing like that. You would have to trigger the animation from code behind.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for your answer, that settles that! Please simply cut and paste your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You should implement a `MyCommandExecuted` event in the view model. The UI component that is executing the animation, should listen to this event e.g. by subscribing to the view model which is the current `DataContext`. The event handler then starts the animation preferably by raising a routed event e.g., `CommandExecuted` which will be handled by the corresponding `EventTrigger`. Alternatively you could start the animation directly in code-behind when handling the `MyCommandExecuted` event. But using `EventTrigger` in XAML is much more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a `MyCommandExecuted` event in the view model. The UI component that is executing the animation, should listen to this event e.g. by subscribing to the view model which is the current `DataContext`.

The event handler of `MyCommandExecuted` then starts the animation preferably by raising a routed event e.g., `CommandExecuted` which will be handled by the corresponding `EventTrigger`.
Alternatively you could start the animation directly in code-behind when handling the `MyCommandExecuted` event. But using `EventTrigger` in XAML is much more convenient.

### Example

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand MyCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand, (param) => true);
  public event EventHandler MyCommandExecuted;

  private void ExecuteMyCommand(object obj)
  {
    // TODO::Implement command operation ...

    OnMyCommandExecuted();
  }

  protected virtual void OnMyCommandExecuted()
  {
    this.MyCommandExecuted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  #region Routed Events

  public static readonly RoutedEvent AnimationRequestedRoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "AnimationRequested",
    RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  public event RoutedEventHandler AnimationRequested
  {
    add => AddHandler(MainWindow.AnimationRequestedRoutedEvent, value);
    remove => RemoveHandler(MainWindow.AnimationRequestedRoutedEvent, value);
  }

  #endregion Routed Events

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.MyCommandExecuted += TriggerAnimation_OnCommandExecuted;

    this.DataContext = viewModel;
  }

  private void TriggerAnimation_OnCommandExecuted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.AnimationRequestedRoutedEvent, this));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Button x:Name="AnimatedButton" 
          Content="Execute My Command"
          Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
          Background="DimGray" />

  <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MainWindow.AnimationRequested">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedButton"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                        FillBehavior="Stop"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.7">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                                   KeyTime="0:0:0" />
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="DarkOrange"
                                   KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Comment: The event on the View Model is just a regular event? I am unfamiliar with subscribing a UI component to VM events.

Comment: After reading your answer I figured the solution would be to create a RoutedEvent in the VM but can it be raised like a traditional event? I've read a lot about RoutedEvents and they seem to be like DependencyProperties, something you add to user controls. I would create a dummy control with a RoutedEvent, attach to the VM event via the DataContext in the code-behind and trigger the control's RoutedEvent which is now in the logical (?) tree?

Comment: No, I think you don't fully understand. My explanation was obviously not good enough, sorry. Or maybe I misunderstood your initial problem. You want to execute an animation when a command, defined in w view model was executed, right? If so, you should define an event e.g. `CommandExecuted` in your view model. A common  CLR event, not a routed event. View model don't define routed commands or routed events or anything `DependencyObject` related. This is strictly UI domain.

Comment: Now that you have this`CommandExecuted`, the control that defines the animation (or any other control in the same route) can subscribe to the view model event e.g. from the constructor or on `FrameworkElement.DataContextChanged`. This control handles the view model event by raising a routed event. This event can be defined anywhere on any `DependencyObject`, since this event is static, it will be globally available. You then define a `EventTrigger` which will handle this routed event, by triggering the animation.

Comment: You basically have two events: a common event raised by the view model and a UI event (routed event) raised by the control as a response to the view model event. No dummy control required. If you want, I could provide a small example to show the flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications. I'm clear on the first part, the VM CLR event. The second part I am not sure about. I would add the code in my Window's constructor to get the VM event and have created a RoutedEvent there? Last part should be straightforward I think.

Comment: I have added a working example to the answer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Animations in WPF are very powerful. You can define a storyboard as a resource that will somehow change a control and then access it as a static resource from any `BeginStoryboard`.

This should accomplish what you want.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="flash" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Button"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    Duration="0:0:0">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                               KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Gold"
                               KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="DimGray"
                             KeyTime="0:0:0.7" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="My Command" Background="DimGray" x:Name="Button">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource flash}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink>
            My Command ...
        </Hyperlink>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Hyperlink.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource flash}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but the Button+Hyperlink scenario was just an example. I want to trigger an animation on controls that are bound to a command, when it is executed. `MyCommand` is not being executed in the Hyperlink in your example and that's what I would want to trigger the animation on the button. `MyCommand` could also be executed directly in the view model by a model event for example. I could find the button and trigger the animation in code-behind but I am asking if it's possible to do this directly in XAML through some event of the command binding.